# CGContextRotateCTM is not rotating UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, core-graphics

I have a subclass of a `UIButton`.

Here's the code I have to attempt to rotate it.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat angle = (-126.0 * M_PI) / 180.0;
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, angle);
}
```

But, nothing's happening.  The view draws to the screen in its default orientation.  Any idea what I'm missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you want to rotate a button, you don't do it by subclassing and modifying drawRect.

All you have to do is:

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```